# Yesod's TH generates incorrect code?

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

I'm making a Yesod subsite and am getting a type error in some Template Haskell-generated code:

```
Yesod\DataSource\Data.hs:19:1:
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Text'
Expected type: () -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route DataSource)
  Actual type: () -> ([[Char]], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route DataSource)
In the first argument of `\ f_amMs x_amMt -> f_amMs () x_amMt ::
                            forall a_amMu.
                            (() -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route a_amMu))
                            -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route a_amMu)', namely
  `helper_amMr'
In the expression:
    \ f_amMs x_amMt -> f_amMs () x_amMt ::
      forall a_amMu.
      (() -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route a_amMu))
      -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)]) -> Maybe (Route a_amMu)
    helper_amMr
```

The problem is clear, but I don't understand why it's generating incorrect code.

The issue occurs in this TH call:

```
mkYesodSubData "DataSource" [parseRoutes|
/ SubHomeR GET
/datasource DataSourceInputR POST GET
|]
```

Specifically, it is caused by the line:

```
/datasource DataSourceInputR POST GET
```

Removing this line fixes the issue.

I'm using Stackage LTS 1.15:

```
remote-repo: stackage-lts-1.15:http://www.stackage.org/snapshot/lts-1.15
```

And I'm inside a cabal sandbox.

Here are the relevant files: https://gist.github.com/BeerendLauwers/774cc432c3ada5b597e1

Any idea?

Comment: If you're sure that it's a bug in Yesod, try to create a minimal example and post an issue on [github](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the generated code expects that you have the `OverloadedStrings` extension enabled in your source file. Try adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

to the top of the source file where you splice in the Template Haskell code (i.e. `Data.hs`).